# How to connect to Python socket server from another network

Tags: python, sockets

I'm new to socket programming and I'm trying to make a server with `socket` module. When working on a local network it works perfectly fine, but the problem comes when I'm trying to run it and connect from two different networks. I've tried many things that I saw on SO and the internet in general.

Server code:

```
import socket
import threading

SERVER = socket.gethostbyname('')
PORT = 12345
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
HEADER = 64
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!DISCONNECT'

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.')
    print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.active_count() - 1}')

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_lenght = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_lenght:
            msg_lenght = int(msg_lenght)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_lenght).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f'[MESSAGE RECIEVED] FROM: {addr}; Message: {msg}')
            conn.send('Message received!'.encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f'[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}')
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()

print(f'IP Address: {SERVER}')
print('[STARTING] Server is starting...')
start()
```

Client code:

```
import socket

SERVER = input('IP Address: ')
PORT = 5050
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
HEADER = 64
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!DISCONNECT'

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_lenght = len(message)
    send_lenght = str(msg_lenght).encode(FORMAT)
    send_lenght += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_lenght))
    client.send(send_lenght)
    client.send(message)

while True:
    user_Input = input('Message: ')
    send(user_Input)
    if user_Input == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
        break
```

I tried making "rules" on the firewall that should make my port public or something. I have also tried different addresses because I was not sure which one to use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *...but the problem comes when I'm trying to run it and connect from two different networks...*  and??? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: That's a routing issue.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It can't connect

Comment: @Keith Well, how do I fix it?

Comment: Not enough information to go on. You would need to know how to set up routes, etc., and know the network topology and addressing scheme.